# nginx - log access and error to pipe and use multilog to log rotate

Tags: nginx, logging, logrotate, pipe, named-pipes

What I am trying to do:
Log rotate nginx access and error log using multilog

My approach:
Log nginx access and error to a pipe, so I can have another process that runs multilog that reads from that pipe and let multilog to do the log rotation

nginx.conf

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access/pipe;
error_log /var/log/nginx/access/pipe;
```

I make sure I created the pipe and give enough permission to whoever to do anything with it

```
$ sudo mkfifo /var/log/nginx/access/pipe /var/log/nginx/error/pipe
$ sudo chmod a+rwx /var/log/nginx/access/pipe /var/log/nginx/error/pipe
```

However, when I start nginx, it will hang as if it is waiting for stdin or something.
I might be missing something here.

I tried simple echo to the pipe

```
$ echo a > /var/log/nginx/access/pipe
```

and it also hangs as if it is waiting for more input. Mayb

Comment: Did you edit the init script to start `multilog` before the Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I think multilog needs to be listening to the pipes before you start Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

[this project](https://github.com/alexgirao/aimant) solves it by properly binding svlogd and [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/LogRotation) semantics, it has a chargen program that simulate nginx behaviour, a stress test and a runit/runsv/svlogd integration example

project tagline: nginx log rotation with daemontools/runit (multilog/svlogd respectively)